# Kafka nodes connection issue after launching 3 or more nodes

Tags: apache-kafka

Had anyone saw the following behavior?

Once a 3rd, 4th...N nodes is launched.. the leader node server.log start showing the following message.

WARN [Controller id=1001, targetBrokerId=1003] Connection to node 1003 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

WARN [Controller id=1001, targetBrokerId=1004] Connection to node 1004 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

When the leader is stoped.. the new leader starts showing the same messages

WARN [Controller id=1002, targetBrokerId=1003] Connection to node 1003 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

WARN [Controller id=1002, targetBrokerId=1004] Connection to node 1004 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

---

Running Kafka 1.1.1 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 on Azure.

The only change made on the original server.properties was to add the zookeeper info (zookeeper.connect=10.1.6.4:2181,10.1.6.5:2181,10.1.6.6:2181)

The nodes(vms) are all reachable and pingable.

Any ideas on how to solve it ?

Thanks
IPVP

Comment: Are you using unique `broker.id` in the Kafka server properties file? You also need to edit that

Comment: Yes. The broker id  unique.